# Unity Video player not working on my android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have two android smartphones( galaxy A6, galaxy 9+) and I'm trying to build my Unity project on smartphones then video player is not working on galaxy 9+ but in case of A6 its is working.

Why were the reasons its not working with galaxy 9+?

Comment: Without any further details, noone can help you. Are there any logs? Any errors? How did you implemented it?

Comment: nothing..(logs or errors) just loading view what i setting while prepare the video

Comment: but on galaxy A6 it is work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you should give a fallback plan like this:

```
m_VideoPlayer.errorReceived += delegate (VideoPlayer videoPlayer, string message)
{
    Debug.LogWarning("[VideoPlayer] Play Movie Error: " + message);
    Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie(m_MoivePath, Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.CancelOnInput, FullScreenMovieScalingMode.AspectFit);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Which video format and codec are you using? After import in Unity, select the video file and enable override for android, and transcode it to VP8. Also you have to set Import audio to false.